# Unable to PLOT multiple data from EXCEL using MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, excel, numpy, matplotlib, xlrd

I've an Excel file with 1000 rows & 300 columns.
I want to plot (column 1) vs (column 2 to 288); my 1st Column is my X Axis, and the rest of the columns are on the Y axis. 
My code is below; I get no display.
There's no error message as such.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wb = load_workbook('CombinedData1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('CombinedData')

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
a = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_column)
b = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_column)

print (sheet_1.max_row)
print (sheet_1.max_column)

for i in range(0, sheet_1.max_row):
    for j in range(1, 7):
        x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=j).value
        y[j] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=j).value
        # z[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=3).value
        print x[i]
        # print y[i]
        plt.plot(x[i], y[i], 'bo-', label='Values')

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the error message if there is any?

Comment: There's no error message as such.
The process I'm following is wrong I guess.
I want to plot (Column 1) vs (Column 2 to 288). But I'm unable to figure out a way.

Comment: Try `plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-', label='Values')` after/outside the for loops

Comment: What you said in comment should have been in your OP from the start.

Comment: What *does* happen?

Comment: Fixed code indentation and spelling; tightened wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using `pandas`:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('CombinedData1.xlsx', sheetname='CombinedData', header=None)
df.plot(x=0)
```

or

```
plt.plot(df[0], df[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following nested loop:

```
for j in range(1, 7):
      for i in range(0, sheet_1.max_row):
               x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=j).value
               y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=j).value
               #z[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=3).value
                print x[i]
               #print y[i]
      plt.plot(x, y, label='Values %d' % j, hold=1)
```

The hold-option will put the 7 individual plots together into one single plot. Furthermore, you should consider using the pandas package for importing and processing the sheet data.

Comment: Why do you recommend pandas? How does pandas simplify the task? Without such information, the recommendation is quite useless!